# Deploy activiti to jetty

Tags: tomcat, jetty, activiti

As recommendation from Activiti

> You’ll need a working Java runtime and Apache Tomcat installation (actually, any web container would work since we only rely on the servlet capability. But we test on Tomcat primarily)

So, activiti will run well on tomcat. But now, Jetty is new Java Servlet container that has good performance, so I want to deploy activiti to jetty.

However, my activiti run too slow when deploying to jetty (the same java_option with tomcat -xmx -xsm ...). Are there anyone has deploy activiti to jetty? Are there any extra configurations for jetty to deploy activiti?

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to these links http://blog.mwrobel.eu/activiti-bpmn-engine-events-via-websockets/ and https://forums.activiti.org/content/run-explorer2 and https://github.com/jbarrez/Activiti-KickStart/blob/master/activiti-kickstart-ui/pom.xml

Comment: That we will run activiti by jetty was embedded in activiti, but now I need to deploy to jetty which was existed (just copy the built war file to jetty).

Comment: Which version of Activiti are you using? What do you mean with 'run too slow', how do you measure/perceive that?

I use Jetty quite a bit and I've never had problems with it when running Activiti.

Comment: I'm using activiti 5.21 with jetty 8. I used 'run too slow' because I have compared with tomcat. do you have any configurations on jetty to run activiti? I have used default configuration with the command below to start jetty. `java -jar -Xms2048m -Xmx4086m start.jar OPTIONS="default,ajp,*" etc/jetty-ajp.xml` (I need enable ajp to implement load-balancing).